# using CListCtrl to display utf-8 characters

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8, mfc

I'm trying to display text in my `CListCtrl` for the last several hours with no success.
I'm using `std::ifstream` to read from .txt file that uses `utf-8` to populate the `CListCtrl`.

"Project properties->Character" set is "not set" and I can't change it to use Unicode, this is an old project originally not written by me.

Also conversion from UTF-8 to ANSI doesn't work, and I can't use boost libraries.
As I read the `CListCtrl` doesn't support UTF-8.

I will be glad to hear any solution that might work, Extended `CListCtrl` to replace the old one etc.. I am using VS2010, .NET4.

Comment: Windows does not support UTF-8.  You will need to use an external library to convert the UTF-8 to UTF-16.  If you have C++11 available to you then this can be done with the standard library.

Comment: not tried it (don't have a windows box with me), but LVITEM is actually an LVITEMA in your build. You may be able to setup a `LVITEMW` directly, using `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,...)` and setting the wide-char text in the wide-version LVITEMW. Been a long time since I tinkered with ListView controls, but worth a shot.

Comment: @МишаСухов: please note that adding code ticks around anything slightly resembling code or an acronym is not an improvement. Some of your previous edits have been restored. You also missed lots of other opportunities to improve, such as grammar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Unicode version of list view APIs (e.g. LVM_SETITEMW). The MBCS version of MFC calls the ANSI versions of Windows APIs which may not be able to display some Unicode characters in your file.

This means you need to send a LVM_SETITEMW message with a LVITEMW structure if you want to change an item, for example. If you have many list controls to change, you can probably write a CListCtrlW class using MFC's code as reference. LVITEMW expects strings to be UTF-16, so you need to convert the string data to UTF-16. You can do this via MultiByteToWideChar or CA2W with the CP_UTF8 code page. Also if you are using a font that cannot handle some Unicode characters from your input, you need to change the font.

If a lot of places in the UI are required to handle Unicode input, you can try move the ANSI part of the business logic out to a DLL then change your main exe project to Unicode.